# Net::LDAP add() failed with no error message. How can I find the reason why the record did not validate?

Tags: ruby, ldap, netldap

I beat myself up for two days as I built a Ruby on Rails application that manages users in LDAP. While fine-tuning the inclusion and formatting of various attributes, I would frequently have `ldap.add()` fail with little feedback other than possibly an exception raised. I usually knew it was a data validation error, such as a missing required attribute or poorly formatted attribute values -- but I could not find anything on the server (Apache DS) or client end that would indicate *which* field failed, or *why* it was failing.

So...how do you see the reason *why* an LDAP add (or replace, delete, open...) failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then I stumbled across `ldap.get_operation_result`, I had a real facepalm moment. I've intentionally recreated several of the issues I painfully solved through careful inspection with `get_operation_result` in my arsenal, and each time it described exactly what the problem was.

This function is useful in the case of rescuing an exception, or if add(), modify(), delete(), etc. simply returns false.

```
 ldap.add(dn: dn, attributes: attributes)
 Rails.logger.info("ldap.add: #{ldap.get_operation_result}")
```

The snippet above saved my sanity, not to mention hours of tedious hunt-and-peck testing.

For example, here is just one part of an error message it revealed that I did not provide the required `sn` attribute:

```
ERR_279 Required attributes [sn(2.5.4.4)] not found within entry uid=david,o=users,dc=example,dc=com"
```

It will also show messages related to bad server connection credentials, etc.

HTH